# Silverlight Isolated Storage and loading big files

Tags: database, windows-phone-7, isolatedstorage

In a Windows Phone 7 application, I would like to query a big XML file (list of cities) stored using [Isolated Storage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3ak841sy.aspx). If I do that this way, will the file be loaded to memory (> 5 mo) ? If so, what other solution do I have?

Edit:

More details. I want to use AutoCompleteBox (http://www.jeff.wilcox.name/2008/10/introducing-autocompletebox/), but instead of using a web service (this is fixed data, no need to be online), I want to query a file/database/isolated storage... I have a fixed list of cities. I said in the comments it's 40k, but it finally seems closer to 1k rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of using isolatedstorage for this, would it be an option for you to use a webservice instead... or do you design your app for an offline approach?

querying a webservice, wcf or json enabled webservice is really simple, and will be easier for you to maintain :)

Comment: I will use a webservice for other stuff in my app, but in this case it's a list of cities. That's pretty fixed, I don't plan to add any city in the future, and storing it locally guaranty quick access. I want to pair it with an AutoCompleteBox

Comment: fair enough.. then you could think about breaking it down into smaller files, one for each city, and use the IsolatedStorageFile.GetFileNames, for listing all files and selecting the appropriate city, will be faster than querying a single file :)

Comment: as I said to Matt, the city *is* the information. I have 40k rows and only two columns per row (zipcode and city name). So 40k files doesn't seem right

Answer (score 0):

Rather than have a big file containing all the data can you not break it down into lots of smaller files. (One for each city?)

You could have a separate file to keep an index of them all if need be. Alternatively, depending on the naming of the files, you may be able to use `IsolatedStorageFile.GetFileNames` to get a list of all files.

Comment: I don't think it will be what i'm looking for. I have a little less than 40k records in my sqlite database (planning to convert it to xml for my wp7 app) containing on each row the name of the city and its zip code. So not sure 40k files is what you have in mind

Comment: @Thomas No 40k files wouldn't be the way to go. (But if you had lots of data about a small number of cities it might.) 26 files based on the first letter of the city name may work though.

Answer (score 0):

I would create my own file format, using, for example, a separator between fields, with one row for each record.
That way you can read your file line-by-line to fill your data structure with these advantages:

1. no need to pull the whole file into memory
2. no XML overhead (in a desktop application it may not be a problem, but in the phone context a 5 MB text file may become quite a bit smaller)

Dumb example:

```
New York City; 12345
Berlin; 25635
...
```

**EDIT:** given that the volume is not that large you don't need any form of indexing or loading on-demand. I would store the cities as stated above -one record per line-, load them in a list and use LINQ to select the items you need. This will probably be fast and keep your application very responsive.

In this case, in my opinion, XML is not the best tool for the job. Your structure is very simple and storing in XML would probably double the file size, which is a concern for a mobile device, and would also slow the parsing, also a concern in this case.

Comment: this seems really hacky for something considered basic usign a database... I want to be able to do simple SELECT LIKE xxx* statements

Comment: I don't see this has "hacky", but to each its own :-) I still believe that in an embedded device optimizing performance and storage is important. By the way if you load your cities in a List (for ex) then with Linq you can do all the Select queries you need.